Ring Video Doorbell / ghost rings with 16 VAC solenoid chimes
I have:

Ring Video Doorbell
(x4) solenoid chime operating on 16 VAC

The chime is a pre-2000's analog device.  Presumably it uses an analog circuit to ring the solenoids in a pattern to make a pleasing song for the doorbell.  It works just fine with an existing push-button doorbell.  However, with a Ring Video Doorbell the chimes ring randomly throughout the day and night.
I suspect that the trickle charge from the Ring device is responsible for this behavior.  It seems to me that a reasonable way to address this problem is to use an opto-isolator.  An off-the-shelf solution from SkyBell like this link seems to provide a decent solution.  Presumably the adapter from SkyBell operates like one of these examples:  link.

I don't need to switch 220V / 50 Hz.  I just need to switch 18 VAC / 60 Hz / 10 A.

What is the likelihood that this circuit will address the problem I have with the Ring Video Doorbell
How would you recommend testing it to demonstrate that it won't "burn my house down"?


why are you asking a question that only you can answer?

In humility.  To solicit advice.  In hopes that somebody else has addressed this problem.  Because the Ring Video Doorbell is very popular.  Because I suspect that this problem exists for other people.

I'm talking about this ... What is the likelihood that this is worth building and trying? ... only you can answer this, nobody else knows what you consider to be worth your effort ... it's like asking would I like to have my house painted blue?

If somebody has built this circuit before and interfaced it to a Ring Video Doorbell, I hope they can inspire me to do the same.  If nobody has done it before, that's valuable to know as well; it means I'm the first and I may not be able to rely upon anyone for advice.

https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/138403/home-made-passive-tablet-pen
I don't understand how my question is different than the one above.  I assume you have the background to understand why I'm asking the question.  How can I make it better so it will be accepted?
